# JQuery - redirect after get request

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Is it possible to redirect user when get request is performed? I have this code:

```
$('.createNewPost').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var notLoggedIn = false;

    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {

        if (data.error === 1) {
            $('.signIn').trigger('click');
            return false;
        }

        // If user is logged in, transfer him to the create new topic page
        // window.location.replace($(this).attr('href'));
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');

    }, 'json');

})
```

I am getting the page I want, but via ajax. I need to redirect user to the next page (both of called methods are working the same).

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not what you think it is inside the callback , it has a new context

Try storing the value outside of the callback:

```
 $('.createNewPost').on('click', function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();

     var notLoggedIn = false;

     var href = $(this).attr('href');

     $.get(href, function(data) {

         if (data.error === 1) {
             $('.signIn').trigger('click');
             return false;
         }

         // If user is logged in, transfer him to the create new topic page
         // window.location.replace($(this).attr('href'));
         window.location.href = href;

     }, 'json');
 });
```

Comment: It works the same way. I am not getting redirect. Noting is changed basically.

Comment: I removed the 'json' part and now it is working o.O. I guess it was waiting for the json response, but since there was no json response the function didn't worked.